# Write performance of Postgresql 9.1 with read-only slave

Tags: postgresql, replication, postgresql-9.1, heroku

I have a Postgresql 9.1 database that is being hosted by Heroku.  It currently has a read-only "follower".  I need to truncate several large tables (over 100GB) of data and reloads them.  Is the read-only follower going to cause an additional overhead to this operation?  Should I drop the follower and recreate it after the process is complete?

Answer (score 1):

Truncate should be a logical operation that should not be too bad disk I/O-wise.  I would not expect a lot of problems there.